# Stripe Transfer to external Account

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to make a donation system for a twitch-like platform.
And I want to use Stripe.

I already make lot of searches. And I know that I need to add an external account for every streamer who want to be paid (by donation).

But I can't add External account, I have this message :

> The provided key 'rk_live_********************2TSc' does not have the
>   required permissions for this endpoint on account
>   'acct_***************d'.  This is a restricted API key, but the
>   required permissions are not available for use by restricted keys.

Am I good with using "External Account" ?
Can you help me with this message please ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create external accounts with restricted keys (ie. the keys that start with `rk_live_`) that only have a subset of permissions.  You need to use your secret keys (ie. the key that starts with `sk_live_`).  You can get this from your dashboard here:

https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys

Comment: I tried with sk_live too..
But I think I've found a solution. I'm understanding that I can't create external account in my default account. I need to create Standard Account